# Entitymanager.flush clears field

Tags: entity-framework, jpa, websphere, entitymanager, openjpa

I am having a problem when updating/merging an entity `A` which has a reference to another entity `B`. `A` also has a reference to an entity `C`.

I create a new instance of the entity `A` from a domain object. Also from this domain object I use the ids to get `B` and `C` by using `entityManager.getReference(<class>, <id>)`. I call `entityManager.merge` and `entityManager.flush()`. So far all is good, the values of both `B` and `C` are present in `A`. When I after the flush do a `entityManager.refresh(A)`, the `B` is cleared(null), but the `C` is still there.

I run sql queries to verify that the value is there before the update. After the flush the FK to `B` is cleared, so when the refresh is called it discovers this.

I do not know what to look for here. Might it be something with how my entities are defined? Persistence-xml? Any tips are much appreciated!

EDIT:
The value of `B` is only cleared if I do not change the reference. If I change the reference of `B` to `B'`, then it is updated correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question did not show the entire context of where I was experiencing the problem. The entity `A` which had a reference to `B`, also had the foreign key field in it. This foreign key field was always null, so setting the entity reference had no effect.